# You are welcome to SOMETHING

Tags: meaning

A native speaker [says](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/you-are-welcome-you-are-welcomed-to.1154775/#post-5955792):

> There's also the expression 'to be welcome to something' which means
> 'you've got it and I'm glad you've got it but I think it's something
> unpleasant and wouldn't want it myself'. A famous mistaken use of this
> idiom was said to be written above the reception desk of a large hotel
> in Moscow: 'If this is your first visit to the USSR you are welcome to
> it'.

I looked this idiom up here https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+welcome+to

**To be expressly or freely permitted to have, use, or do something.**

You're welcome to the spare bed if you want to spend the night here.

Is it the case that the ironic meaning is not in the dictionary or is the native wrong?

Comment: Dictionaries do not typically assign separate meanings to ironic usages. **you are welcome to [something]** isn't an idiom, as we can understand the meaning directly from the words in context: take it, or have if, if you like or if it suits you.

Comment: It could be used that way in specific contexts.  It would really depend on the situation and how it is said, with a specific tone of voice. For example if you say it in a dismissive way.  It doesn't necessarily mean it's something unpleasant, could be for other reasons - perhaps something that is broken, not working, or of no use to you, surplus to requirements, etc, etc.

Comment: The phrase "you're welcome to [something]" is used so frequently to mean "I have no desire to have it, please take it, if it suits you" that it could be understood as simply a form of politeness in situations where there's some doubt whether a thing can be taken without offending the other person. When that doubt doesn't exist, as is the case if the thing has already been taken, then some *snarkiness* can be involved on the part of the speaker: "I certainly wouldn't want it." Perhaps there's a shred of contextual irony there, as the word  "welcome" has connotations of *generosity*.

Comment: So, does the remark that 'If this is your first visit to the USSR you are welcome to it'. has this pun, hold water?

Comment: user1425, it's not a pun.

Comment: After one's grandmother died, and the family were clearing her house, and apportioning her possessions, there would be no 'irony' or 'snark' (horrible American word!) in saying 'You're welcome to everything else, but I want the piano'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: It ***is*** a pun! Or at least, it's "pun-like wordplay": *If this is your first visit to the USSR you're welcome to it. **Please feel free to take it, because we don't want it.***

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I suppose it _might_ be considered an unintentional homographic pun.

Comment: The ironic meaning could have been intentional, I suppose. I do recall that Russian ladies, once a month, used to say that the 'Red Army' had arrived. Maybe they still do?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I seriously doubt there was ever an actual sign *anywhere, ever* in the USSR with that text! Unless feasibly it was put up as a joke in some hotel that specialized in accomodating Anglophone guests, but that seems unlikely. The only reason we're seeing it here is because it's being *presented* as a joke / pun. You go to a stand-up comedy gig, and the star of the show starts off with *A funny think happened on the train when I was traveling here tonight...* Do you think it's likely what he says next accurately describes something that really happened earlier? (I think not! :)

Comment: ...it's on a par with [*Finally! I got a **round tuit**!*](https://www.reddit.com/r/GetMotivated/comments/16xgw1/i_got_this_from_my_grandma_she_said_it_always/) - except that one probably only really works for the natives!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - yes. It's also supposed to have been put up at the airport. Often seen in lists of 'funny' signs in foreign places, like _in the window of a furrier's shop in Sweden : Fur coats made for ladies from their own skin._

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the use you are referring to is 'ironic'.

When we *genuinely* say someone is 'welcome to' something, we are offering it to them - saying they can have it.

When people say it in anger, what they normally mean is that someone has taken something either without their knowledge, against their wishes, or contrary to their advice. Saying "you are welcome to it" means that you personally *do not, or would not want it*. In the case of something taken, perhaps you mean that you do not want it *back*. The example in your quote about a visit to the USSR doesn't make much sense, but that is because it was probably an example of a bad English translation that *almost* sounds like it is this negative use of the expression.

If someone took something you wouldn't normally have offered, saying this could be considered sarcastic, because it is not really meant. A more extreme example of this in practice might be a jilted wife saying to the woman who stole her husband "*you're welcome to him*". This would imply that she doesn't want him back and so is not really sarcastic in the truest sense, but still biting.

Answer (score 0):

The definition you found in the dictionary is accurate, and is the basic meaning of the expression in both forms. It's mostly used to mean, "I would be happy for you to take it or to do it", with no other implied meaning.

This expression can also have one or two extra inferred meanings: that the object is worthless to me, or a caution about the object or doing the action.

The speaker in your linked forum makes a couple mistakes. First, he says that this expression means the listener already has the object, which isn't true. He also implies it *always* includes *both* of these nuanced meanings, but that's not true either. It could have one additional meaning, or the other, or both, all depending on the context, but it usually just means what the dictionary says.

In the sign about the USSR, the humorous meaning is that it sounds like "We don't want the USSR, so if you want it, you can just take it." It doesn't imply anything unpleasant about the USSR, just that the owner cares so little about it that they're happy to give it away.

For an example that implies a caution about the object, here's a clip from [YouTube](https://youtu.be/qBhf8JVl3oQ?t=1478):

> You're **more than welcome to** tell me how bad it is or why you can't, because, or what, but it's just not true.

Here the speaker tells the audience they are free to talk about what's wrong, or why they can't do something, but **cautions** them that it's useless to talk that way.